# pure-ftpd not using ciphers?

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, login

I just tried to setup a pure-ftpd server. All goes well, i can login, portforwarding is ok, it gives me the certificate i got from letsencrypt, but: for some reason it wont use the cipher i've chosen for.

I've tried multiple ways. Using the command line:

`pure-ftpd [...] -J ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384`

Using the file /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/TLSCipherSuite:

`ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA`

when im connecting, my session details are:

`Protocol: TLS1.2
Key exchange: ECDHE-RSA
Cipher: AES-128-GCM
MAC: AEAD`

Im using the client Filezilla 3.18.0 on OSX. The server is running on Ubuntu 16.04.

What am i missing? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: This may be better off on serverfault. But, I noticed the same thing on a cPanel v60 (CentOS 6.8) server today. Does anyone have any ideas? The output of nmap (from another box) using ssl-enum-ciphers shows that not only are the ciphers seemingly unchanged, but TLSv1.0 is still available. Is the output of `nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 21 123.123.123.123` somehow *cached*?